# How to trigger windowClosing() event in an applet when the browser gets closed

Tags: java, swing, awt, japplet

How can I trigger the `windowClosing()` event, to do some cleaning in an applet, when I close the browser?

Answer (score 1):

`destroy()` method should be called before the browser unloads the object. Some times destroy method won't get sufficient time to close the window. `destroy()` should be called by the environment itself and if you think its not being called then you might declare `public finalize()`

```
public void finalize () {
    destroy();
}
```